# How to achieve circular marker in google map using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

I am using **react-google-maps** to implement map.
I am able to achieve default maker in particular lat and lan

But i am trying to achieve circular marker. I am using `google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE` to achieve circular marker, but getting error

[image]

Could you please guide me how to achieve this?

**Code**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker } from 'react-google-maps';

class HomeComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            data: [
                { "name": "Delhi", "coordinates": { lng: 77.1025, lat: 28.7041 }, "mag": 3.3 },
                { "name": "Seoul", "coordinates": { lng: 126.9780, lat: 37.5665 }, "mag": 5.0 },
                { "name": "Shanghai", "coordinates": { lng: 121.4737, lat: 31.2304 }, "mag": 3.3 },
                { "name": "Beijing", "coordinates": { lng: 116.4074, lat: 39.9042 }, "mag": 5.0 },
                { "name": "Mumbai", "coordinates": { lng: 72.8777, lat: 19.0760 }, "mag": 3.3 },
                { "name": "Moscow", "coordinates": { lng: 37.6173, lat: 55.7558 }, "mag": 5.2 },
                { "name": "Dhaka", "coordinates": { lng: 90.4125, lat: 23.8103 }, "mag": 1.5 },
                { "name": "Kolkata", "coordinates": { lng: 88.3639, lat: 22.5726 }, "mag": 4.9 },
                { "name": "Istanbul", "coordinates": { lng: 28.9784, lat: 41.0082 }, "mag": 2.1 },
                { "name": "Tampa", "coordinates": { lng: -82.452606, lat: 27.964157 }, "mag": 3.1 },
                { "name": "canada", "coordinates": { lat: 56.1304, lng: -106.3468 }, "mag": 6.1 },
                { "name": "Karnataka", "coordinates": { lat: 15.3173, lng: 75.7139 }, "mag": 6.1 },
            ]
        }
    }

    render() {
        const GoogleMapExample = withGoogleMap(props => (
            <GoogleMap
                defaultCenter={{ lat: 40.756795, lng: -73.954298 }}
                defaultZoom={4}
            >
                { 
                    this.state.data.map(item =>
                        <Marker
                            icon={{
                                path: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
                                fillColor: 'red',
                                fillOpacity: .2,
                                scale: Math.pow(2, item.mag) / 2,
                                strokeColor: 'white',
                                strokeWeight: .5}
                            }
                            key={item.id}
                            title={item.name}
                            name={item.name}
                            position={{ lat: item.coordinates.lat, lng: item.coordinates.lng }}
                        />
                    )
                }
            </GoogleMap>
        ));
        return (
            <div>
                <GoogleMapExample
                    containerElement={<div style={{ height: `500px`, width: '100%' }} />}
                    mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default HomeComponent;
```

Here is link for [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-tereshkova-dyne2?file=/src/App.js)

**Expected Output**

[image]

Comment: Can you add an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) in your question? You can use [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/).

Comment: @Pagemag updated my question with CodeSandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`google` is not really `undefined` since you have included it in your `index.html`. In fact if you do `console.log(google)`, you will see the object is properly accessible and is defined.

Regarding the circles, you can use `google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE` instead of `google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE`

[image: Edit recursing-cohen-5ci1i]

Comment: Ok understood, but is there any parameter present in `react-google-maps` by which we can achieve circular marker?

Comment: What do you mean? If you view my sandbox its already circular & very similar to the image at the bottom of your question. If you want to customize it further I suppose you can alter the props or did you mean [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#circle_add) type of implementation? you can use [custom image data](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#MarkerOptions.icon) as well if needed

Comment: Sorry, i didn't see that. but i am using `google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE` still it is showing google is not defined

Comment: is it required to load map script in component?

Comment: Regarding `google` still being undefined (although i've explained already that it is not - it is simply the work of eslint) - just do what I did on my sandbox and include this comment on top of your component: `/*global google*/`. If it is not working for your project then use `window.google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE`. If that still does not work then use `withScriptjs` to load the script in the component instead of `index.html`. Refer to Step 3 & Step 4 of this [documentation](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/)